# how i can get ntfs data on ext4 partition?

Tags: ext4, ntfs

1] i have installed kali linux on my laptop. but it converted all my hard disk partition into ext4 formate. so my old data on ntfs partition is not showing on ext4 partition. so, how i can get my old data back..
2] andthen i tried to install windows 10 back but it not showing any partition at installation process..
 i want to install windows 10 back and want to get all my data back.. 
please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you repartition a hard disk drive, all the data on that hard disk drive is gone.

That's why it's always recommended to make a backup of your data before making drastic changes (like changing operating systems) to your computer.

Comment: is there any possibility to get data back using test disk ??

Comment: You might be able to get _some_ of it, if you're lucky, but much of it will have been overwritten or garbled by the new partitions and system files.